# DisplayedLanguage to languageTag using Locale?

Tags: java, kotlin

I use [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and have displayed language in `String`, for example "English". Is it possible to convert it to language tag(`en`)?

Comment: Please share the code you manipulate, that is strange to mention 'Locale' to tell us after you only have a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

No, localized names of languages are not mapped back to the standardized language code.

Language code leads to localized language name, but not vice versa.

## Localized output, not input

Use localized text such as "English" for presentation to user only, not as key data.

We have [international standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code) for precisely identifying human languages and cultures such as `en` for English & `US` for United States culture — use those as key data for purposes such as obtaining a Locale object.

For example:

- "English" (the word “English” in English)
- "anglais" (the word “English” in French)
- "անգլերեն" (the word “English” in Armenian)

… are *outputs*, not *inputs*.

This is the difference between [`Locale#getLanguage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage()) and [`Locale#getDisplayLanguage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage(java.util.Locale)). The first returns a code while the second returns a localized name of that language. Ditto for [`Locale#getCountry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getCountry()) and [`Locale#getDisplayCountry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry(java.util.Locale)).

For fun, let's look at all possible names for “English”.

```java
for ( Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales() )
{
    System.out.println( Locale.US.getLanguage() + " ➜ " + Locale.US.getDisplayLanguage( locale ) + " in locale: " + locale.getDisplayName( Locale.US ) );
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/qlag61).

Here is the partial results, truncated per the limit of an Answer's size in Stack Overflow.

```
en ➜ English in locale: 
en ➜ אנגלית in locale: Hebrew
en ➜ อังกฤษ in locale: Thai (Thai, Thailand)
en ➜ English in locale: Low German
en ➜ iňlis dili in locale: Turkmen (Latin, Turkmenistan)
en ➜ እንግሊዝ in locale: Tigrinya (Ethiopia)
en ➜ ஆங்கிலம் in locale: Tamil (Singapore)
en ➜ angļu in locale: Latvian
en ➜ English in locale: English (Niue)
en ➜ 英语 in locale: Chinese (Simplified, Singapore)
en ➜  in locale: Fulah (Adlam, Liberia)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Jamaica)
en ➜ yaman in locale: Kako
en ➜ eaŋgalsgiella in locale: Northern Sami (Latin, Norway)
en ➜ انگريزي in locale: Sindhi (Arabic)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Bolivia)
en ➜ ཨིང་ལིཤ་ཁ in locale: Dzongkha (Bhutan)
en ➜ ইংলিস in locale: Manipuri
en ➜ ענגליש in locale: Yiddish
en ➜ engleski in locale: Bosnian (Bosnia & Herzegovina)
en ➜ engelšćina in locale: Lower Sorbian (Germany)
en ➜ Englesch in locale: Luxembourgish (Latin, Luxembourg)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Liberia)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Chad)
en ➜ angličtina in locale: Czech
en ➜ Αγγλικά in locale: Greek
en ➜ Thok liŋli̱thni in locale: Nuer (Latin, South Sudan)
en ➜ Engels in locale: Afrikaans
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Mauritania)
en ➜ Kiingereza in locale: Swahili (Uganda)
en ➜ eŋgâlâskielâ in locale: Inari Sami
en ➜ iňlis dili in locale: Turkmen (Turkmenistan)
en ➜ енглески in locale: Serbian (Cyrillic, Montenegro)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Egypt)
en ➜ engelšćina in locale: Lower Sorbian
en ➜ англисаг in locale: Ossetic (Cyrillic, Georgia)
en ➜ Èdè Gẹ̀ẹ́sì in locale: Yoruba (Nigeria)
en ➜ eaŋgalsgiella in locale: Northern Sami (Norway)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Koyra Chiini
en ➜ English in locale: English (Palau)
en ➜ angielski in locale: Polish (Poland)
en ➜ енглески in locale: Serbian (Serbia and Montenegro)
en ➜ अङ्ग्रेजी in locale: Nepali (India)
en ➜ Kɨŋgele in locale: Aghem (Latin, Cameroon)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Western Sahara)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Bosnian (Latin, Bosnia & Herzegovina)
en ➜ English in locale: Low German (Germany)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard & Jan Mayen)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (United States)
en ➜ आङ्ग्लभाषा in locale: Sanskrit
en ➜ English in locale: English (United States, Computer)
en ➜ inglês in locale: Portuguese (Macao SAR China)
en ➜ 英语 in locale: Chinese (Simplified)
en ➜ Englesch in locale: Luxembourgish (Luxembourg)
en ➜ engelšćina in locale: Lower Sorbian (Latin, Germany)
en ➜ enska in locale: Icelandic (Latin, Iceland)
en ➜ Ingiriisi in locale: Somali (Kenya)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Zarma (Niger)
en ➜ անգլերեն in locale: Armenian (Armenian, Armenia)
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Ghana)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (St. Pierre & Miquelon)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Comoros)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian (Norway, Nynorsk)
en ➜ angielski in locale: Polish (Latin, Poland)
en ➜ Kɨŋgele in locale: Aghem (Cameroon)
en ➜ અંગ્રેજી in locale: Gujarati (Gujarati, India)
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Teso
en ➜ İngilizce in locale: Turkish (Turkey)
en ➜ ingeles in locale: Basque
en ➜ English in locale: Kalaallisut (Latin, Greenland)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Mauritania)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Dominican Republic)
en ➜ английский in locale: Russian
en ➜ ingilis in locale: Azerbaijani
en ➜ Inggris in locale: Sundanese (Latin)
en ➜ انگلیسی in locale: Persian
en ➜ English in locale: Kalaallisut (Greenland)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Nauru)
en ➜ isi-Ngisi in locale: North Ndebele
en ➜ ағылшын тілі in locale: Kazakh
en ➜ English in locale: Low German (Latin, Germany)
en ➜ Icyongereza in locale: Kinyarwanda (Latin, Rwanda)
en ➜ անգլերեն in locale: Armenian
en ➜ English in locale: English (Australia)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Cyprus)
en ➜ İngilizce in locale: Turkish (Latin, Turkey)
en ➜ እንግሊዝ in locale: Tigrinya (Eritrea)
en ➜ Thok liŋli̱thni in locale: Nuer (South Sudan)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Rwanda)
en ➜ Kiingeeza in locale: Shambala
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Luo
en ➜ Englesch in locale: Luxembourgish
en ➜ engleski in locale: Croatian (Latin, Croatia)
en ➜ Inggris in locale: Sundanese
en ➜ lingɛlɛ́sa in locale: Lingala (Congo - Kinshasa)
en ➜ ngilísè in locale: Ngiemboon (Cameroon)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Zarma (Latin, Niger)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Israel)
en ➜ Ingilishi in locale: Makhuwa-Meetto
en ➜ ଇଂରାଜୀ in locale: Odia (India)
en ➜ انګليسي in locale: Pashto (Arabic, Afghanistan)
en ➜ ingilis in locale: Azerbaijani (Latin)
en ➜ ஆங்கிலம் in locale: Tamil
en ➜ Kɨɨngeréesa in locale: Langi
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Syria)
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Luo (Latin, Kenya)
en ➜ riingɛrís in locale: Bafia (Cameroon)
en ➜ དབྱིན་ཇིའི་སྐད། in locale: Tibetan
en ➜ инглиз in locale: Tatar (Russia)
en ➜ Ingliffa in locale: Oromo (Kenya)
en ➜ English in locale: English (American Samoa)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Vanuatu)
en ➜ 英文 in locale: Chinese (Taiwan)
en ➜ انگريزي in locale: Sindhi (India)
en ➜ kutitab Uingeresa in locale: Kalenjin
en ➜ ngilísè in locale: Ngiemboon (Latin, Cameroon)
en ➜ अंग्रेज़ी in locale: Maithili
en ➜ inglês in locale: Portuguese (Mozambique)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Niger)
en ➜ inglês in locale: Friulian (Latin, Italy)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Asturian (Latin, Spain)
en ➜ Hiingereza in locale: Bena (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ Kiingeeza in locale: Shambala (Tanzania)
en ➜ အင်္ဂလိပ် in locale: Burmese (Myanmar, Myanmar (Burma))
en ➜ English in locale: English (Jersey)
en ➜ lingɛlɛ́sa in locale: Lingala (Central African Republic)
en ➜ inglizcha in locale: Uzbek (Afghanistan)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Danish (Latin, Denmark)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Christmas Island)
en ➜ Borɔfo in locale: Akan (Latin, Ghana)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Austria)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Galician
en ➜ енглески in locale: Serbian (Cyrillic)
en ➜ 英文 in locale: Cantonese (Simplified, China)
en ➜  in locale: Fulah (Adlam)
en ➜ ಇಂಗ್ಲಿಷ್ in locale: Kannada (India)
en ➜ Béarla in locale: Irish
en ➜ Ingles Simi in locale: Quechua
en ➜ English in locale: English (Tanzania)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Puerto Rico)
en ➜ zah Anglofoŋ in locale: Mundang
en ➜ Inggris in locale: Javanese
en ➜ انګليسي in locale: Pashto
en ➜ Chirungu in locale: Shona
en ➜ អង់គ្លេស in locale: Khmer
en ➜ ⵜⴰⵏⴳⵍⵉⵣⵜ in locale: Standard Moroccan Tamazight
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (New Caledonia)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish
en ➜ Aŋgɛlúshi in locale: Ngomba
en ➜ Beurla in locale: Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom)
en ➜ Änglisch in locale: Swiss German
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Cameroon)
en ➜ Engliš in locale: Walser (Latin, Switzerland)
en ➜ ਅੰਗਰੇਜ਼ੀ in locale: Punjabi (Gurmukhi, India)
en ➜ انگریزی in locale: Urdu (Arabic, Pakistan)
en ➜ Ínglish in locale: Nigerian Pidgin (Latin, Nigeria)
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Teso (Uganda)
en ➜ Ingles in locale: Cebuano
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian (Latin, Norway)
en ➜ ইংরেজি in locale: Bangla (Bangla, Bangladesh)
en ➜ eŋgâlâskielâ in locale: Inari Sami (Latin, Finland)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Netherlands)
en ➜ lingɛlɛ́sa in locale: Lingala (Congo - Brazzaville)
en ➜ अङ्ग्रेजी in locale: Nepali (Devanagari, Nepal)
en ➜ ఇంగ్లీష్ in locale: Telugu
en ➜ ingilis in locale: Azerbaijani (Azerbaijan)
en ➜ angleščina in locale: Slovenian
en ➜ Αγγλικά in locale: Greek (Cyprus)
en ➜ इंग्रजी in locale: Marathi (India)
en ➜ îngilîzî in locale: Kurdish (Turkey)
en ➜ Turanci in locale: Hausa
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Gusii (Latin, Kenya)
en ➜ ئینگیلیسی in locale: Northern Luri (Iran)
en ➜ Änglisch in locale: Swiss German (France)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Honduras)
en ➜ angol in locale: Hungarian (Hungary)
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Senegal)
en ➜ Ishingelesa in locale: Sangu
en ➜ anglisht in locale: Albanian (North Macedonia)
en ➜ енглески in locale: Serbian (Cyrillic, Bosnia & Herzegovina)
en ➜ английски in locale: Bulgarian (Cyrillic, Bulgaria)
en ➜ Ingiriisi in locale: Somali (Latin, Somalia)
en ➜ inglise in locale: Estonian (Estonia)
en ➜ Kiingereza in locale: Swahili
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Oman)
en ➜ Ingelsk in locale: Western Frisian (Netherlands)
en ➜ Ngɛ̄lɛ̄n in locale: Kwasio
en ➜ İngilizce in locale: Turkish (Cyprus)
en ➜ angļu in locale: Latvian (Latin, Latvia)
en ➜ inglizcha in locale: Uzbek (Latin, Uzbekistan)
en ➜ ئینگیلیسی in locale: Northern Luri (Iraq)
en ➜ English in locale: Duala (Cameroon)
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German (Italy)
en ➜ inglês in locale: Portuguese (Latin, Brazil)
en ➜ ꕶꕱ in locale: Vai (Vai)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Tunisia)
en ➜ енглески in locale: Serbian (Serbia)
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German (Switzerland)
en ➜ Kiingereza in locale: Swahili (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (French Polynesia)
en ➜ inglês in locale: Portuguese (Equatorial Guinea)
en ➜ અંગ્રેજી in locale: Gujarati
en ➜ Kyingereza in locale: Vunjo (Tanzania)
en ➜ Kyingereza in locale: Machame (Tanzania)
en ➜ Anglisy in locale: Malagasy (Latin, Madagascar)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Tuvalu)
en ➜ ອັງກິດ in locale: Lao
en ➜ English in locale: English (Pitcairn Islands)
en ➜ Lingelesa in locale: Luba-Katanga (Latin, Congo - Kinshasa)
en ➜ 英语 in locale: Chinese (Simplified, Hong Kong SAR China)
en ➜ Engels in locale: Dutch (Netherlands)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Guyana)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Bosnian (Latin)
en ➜ angle in locale: Jola-Fonyi (Senegal)
en ➜ англисаг in locale: Ossetic
en ➜ Engels in locale: Dutch (Curaçao)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Algeria)
en ➜ inglês in locale: Portuguese (Switzerland)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Equatorial Guinea)
en ➜ እንግሊዝኛ in locale: Amharic
en ➜ English in locale: English (Nigeria)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Côte d’Ivoire)
en ➜ Gĩthungũ in locale: Kikuyu (Kenya)
en ➜ anglese in locale: Interlingua (world)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Pakistan)
en ➜ 英语 in locale: Chinese (China)
en ➜ English in locale: English (St. Lucia)
en ➜ Icyongereza in locale: Kinyarwanda
en ➜ अंग्रेज़ी in locale: Bodo (India)
en ➜  in locale: Fulah (Adlam, Burkina Faso)
en ➜ English in locale: Manx (Isle of Man)
en ➜ English in locale: Cornish (Latin, United Kingdom)
en ➜ angilɛkan in locale: Bambara (Latin, Mali)
en ➜ íŋgilísé in locale: Yangben (Latin, Cameroon)
en ➜ англиски in locale: Macedonian (North Macedonia)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Trinidad & Tobago)
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Taita
en ➜ angleščina in locale: Slovenian (Slovenia)
en ➜ Anglëe in locale: Sango (Latin, Central African Republic)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Koyraboro Senni
en ➜ englanti in locale: Finnish (Latin, Finland)
en ➜ English in locale: Xhosa (South Africa)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Belgium)
en ➜ Aŋgɛlúshi in locale: Ngomba (Cameroon)
en ➜  in locale: Fulah (Adlam, Niger)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Venezuela)
en ➜ Kĩngeretha in locale: Meru (Kenya)
en ➜ Anglisy in locale: Malagasy
en ➜ इंग्रजी in locale: Marathi
en ➜ English in locale: English (Bermuda)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)
en ➜ inglês in locale: Sena
en ➜ ingles in locale: Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde)
en ➜ English in locale: Metaʼ
en ➜ Tiếng Anh in locale: Vietnamese (Vietnam)
en ➜ English in locale: English (United States)
en ➜ angle in locale: Morisyen (Mauritius)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Burkina Faso)
en ➜ ਅੰਗਰੇਜ਼ੀ in locale: Punjabi (Gurmukhi)
en ➜ inglese in locale: Italian (San Marino)
en ➜ انگلیسی in locale: Persian (Arabic, Iran)
en ➜ आङ्ग्लभाषा in locale: Sanskrit (Devanagari, India)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Mayotte)
en ➜ અંગ્રેજી in locale: Gujarati (India)
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Cameroon)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Asturian
en ➜ Ingliż in locale: Maltese (Latin, Malta)
en ➜ englanti in locale: Finnish (Finland)
en ➜ 英文 in locale: Cantonese (Simplified)
en ➜ anglès in locale: Catalan (France)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Serbian (Latin, Bosnia & Herzegovina)
en ➜  in locale: Chakma (Chakma, Bangladesh)
en ➜ англійська in locale: Ukrainian (Cyrillic, Ukraine)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Djibouti)
en ➜ اَنگیٖزۍ in locale: Kashmiri (Arabic)
en ➜  in locale: Fulah (Adlam, Guinea-Bissau)
en ➜ Turanci in locale: Hausa (Ghana)
en ➜ ענגליש in locale: Yiddish (Hebrew, world)
en ➜ Engels in locale: Afrikaans (Latin, South Africa)
en ➜ እንግሊዝ in locale: Tigrinya (Ethiopic, Ethiopia)
en ➜ lea fakapālangi in locale: Tongan (Latin, Tonga)
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German (Belgium)
en ➜ እንግሊዝኛ in locale: Amharic (Ethiopic, Ethiopia)
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Guinea-Bissau)
en ➜ Orungyereza in locale: Chiga
en ➜ 英文 in locale: Chinese (Macao SAR China)
en ➜ zah Anglofoŋ in locale: Mundang (Latin, Cameroon)
en ➜ Orungyereza in locale: Nyankole (Uganda)
en ➜ Inggeris in locale: Malay (Malaysia)
en ➜ Icongereza in locale: Rundi (Latin, Burundi)
en ➜ ஆங்கிலம் in locale: Tamil (Sri Lanka)
en ➜ riingɛrís in locale: Bafia
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German (Latin, Germany)
en ➜ Saesneg in locale: Welsh
en ➜ Ingles in locale: Cebuano (Philippines)
en ➜ anglisht in locale: Albanian
en ➜ anglais in locale: French
en ➜ англисӣ in locale: Tajik (Tajikistan)
en ➜ Kyingereza in locale: Vunjo (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ Ingles Simi in locale: Quechua (Peru)
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Ecuador)
en ➜ англиски in locale: Macedonian (Cyrillic, North Macedonia)
en ➜  in locale: Fulah (Adlam, Cameroon)
en ➜ Lungereza in locale: Ganda (Uganda)
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Niger)
en ➜ i-English in locale: Zulu (South Africa)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Latin, France)
en ➜ Inggris in locale: Sundanese (Latin, Indonesia)
en ➜ Orungyereza in locale: Chiga (Uganda)
en ➜ Änglesch in locale: Colognian (Germany)
en ➜ Lungereza in locale: Ganda
en ➜ английский in locale: Russian (Russia)
en ➜ Ínglish in locale: Nigerian Pidgin (Nigeria)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Dominica)
en ➜ انگريزي in locale: Sindhi
en ➜ אנגלית in locale: Hebrew (Hebrew, Israel)
en ➜ Béarla in locale: Irish (Ireland)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Burundi)
en ➜ 英文 in locale: Cantonese (China)
en ➜ englais in locale: Romansh (Latin, Switzerland)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Samoa)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Luxembourg)
en ➜ Ingiriisi in locale: Somali
en ➜ Ingarihi in locale: Maori (New Zealand)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Eritrea)
en ➜ Taglizit in locale: Kabyle
en ➜ Thok liŋli̱thni in locale: Nuer
en ➜ Chirungu in locale: Shona (Zimbabwe)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Ceuta & Melilla)
en ➜ Béarla in locale: Irish (United Kingdom)
en ➜ อังกฤษ in locale: Thai (Thailand, TH, Thai Digits)
en ➜ अंग्रेज़ी in locale: Hindi
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Seychelles)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Sierra Leone)
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Nigeria)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian (Norway)
en ➜  in locale: Fulah (Adlam, Nigeria)
en ➜ 英文 in locale: Chinese (Traditional, Macao SAR China)
en ➜ English in locale: English (St. Helena)
en ➜ ꕶꕱ in locale: Vai
en ➜ انگريزي in locale: Sindhi (Arabic, Pakistan)
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German (Luxembourg)
en ➜ Ingarihi in locale: Maori
en ➜ Ingliż in locale: Maltese
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German (Germany)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian Nynorsk (Latin, Norway)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Denmark)
en ➜ íŋgilísé in locale: Yangben
en ➜ Ingiriisi in locale: Somali (Djibouti)
en ➜ anglų in locale: Lithuanian (Lithuania)
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Kamba
en ➜ engleză in locale: Romanian
en ➜ angla in locale: Esperanto (world)
en ➜ انګليسي in locale: Pashto (Pakistan)
en ➜ Yevugbe in locale: Ewe
en ➜ English in locale: English (U.S. Outlying Islands)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Slovenia)
en ➜ ꕶꕱ in locale: Vai (Vai, Liberia)
en ➜ ອັງກິດ in locale: Lao (Laos)
en ➜ ᎩᎵᏏ in locale: Cherokee
en ➜ Kiingereza in locale: Rombo (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Lebanon)
en ➜ ئینگیلیسی in locale: Northern Luri (Arabic, Iran)
en ➜ Engels in locale: Afrikaans (South Africa)
en ➜ अंगरेजी in locale: Dogri
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Guinea)
en ➜ Änglesch in locale: Colognian (Latin, Germany)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Belize)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (United Arab Emirates)
en ➜ angla in locale: Esperanto (Latin, world)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Croatian (Croatia)
en ➜ Kiingereza in locale: Rombo (Tanzania)
en ➜ ইংৰাজী in locale: Assamese
en ➜ inglese in locale: Italian
en ➜ اَنگیٖزۍ in locale: Kashmiri (India)
en ➜ အင်္ဂလိပ် in locale: Burmese (Myanmar (Burma))
en ➜ англи in locale: Mongolian (Mongolia)
en ➜ انگریزی in locale: Urdu (Pakistan)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Danish (Denmark)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Micronesia)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Belgium)
en ➜ ꑱꇩꉙ in locale: Sichuan Yi
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Wallis & Futuna)
en ➜ انگلیسی in locale: Mazanderani (Iran)
en ➜ Engels in locale: Nama
en ➜ English in locale: English (Singapore)
en ➜ kutitab Uingeresa in locale: Kalenjin (Kenya)
en ➜ Tanglizt in locale: Central Atlas Tamazight
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Gambia)
en ➜ инглиз in locale: Tatar (Cyrillic, Russia)
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Teso (Latin, Uganda)
en ➜ inglês in locale: Friulian
en ➜ Ingliffa in locale: Oromo
en ➜ Kiingeredha in locale: Asu (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ Hiingereza in locale: Bena (Tanzania)
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Guinea)
en ➜ angleščina in locale: Slovenian (Latin, Slovenia)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Sudan)
en ➜ अंग्रेज़ी in locale: Maithili (Devanagari, India)
en ➜ 英語 in locale: Japanese (Japan, JP, Japanese Calendar)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (El Salvador)
en ➜ inglês in locale: Portuguese (Brazil)
en ➜ ইংলিস in locale: Manipuri (Bangla, India)
en ➜ ഇംഗ്ലീഷ് in locale: Malayalam (India)
en ➜ Béarla in locale: Irish (Latin, Ireland)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Falkland Islands)
en ➜ enska in locale: Icelandic (Iceland)
en ➜ Hɔp u ŋgisì in locale: Basaa (Latin, Cameroon)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Diego Garcia)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Croatian
en ➜ inglês in locale: Portuguese (São Tomé & Príncipe)
en ➜ Borɔfo in locale: Akan (Ghana)
en ➜ anglų in locale: Lithuanian
en ➜ English in locale: Uzbek (Arabic, Afghanistan)
en ➜  in locale: Chakma
en ➜ English in locale: English (Sweden)
en ➜ 英语 in locale: Chinese (Simplified, China)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Latin America)
en ➜ lingɛlɛ́sa in locale: Lingala (Latin, Congo - Kinshasa)
en ➜ yaman in locale: Kako (Latin, Cameroon)
en ➜ English in locale: English
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Gusii (Kenya)
en ➜ Änglisch in locale: Swiss German (Liechtenstein)
en ➜  in locale: Chakma (Bangladesh)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Canary Islands)
en ➜ anglès in locale: Catalan
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Tunisia)
en ➜ angilɛkan in locale: Bambara (Mali)
en ➜ English in locale: Cornish (United Kingdom)
en ➜ ਅੰਗਰੇਜ਼ੀ in locale: Punjabi (Pakistan)
en ➜ ئىنگلىزچە in locale: Uyghur (China)
en ➜ Kyingereza in locale: Machame (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ Gĩthungũ in locale: Kikuyu (Latin, Kenya)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Brazil)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Koyra Chiini (Mali)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Solomon Islands)
en ➜ དབྱིན་ཇིའི་སྐད། in locale: Tibetan (Tibetan, China)
en ➜ ᎩᎵᏏ in locale: Cherokee (United States)
en ➜ Icyongereza in locale: Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)
en ➜ ⵜⴰⵏⴳⵍⵉⵣⵜ in locale: Tachelhit (Tifinagh, Morocco)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Iraq)
en ➜ Orungyereza in locale: Nyankole
en ➜ англиски in locale: Macedonian
en ➜ ᱟᱝᱜᱽᱨᱮᱡᱤ in locale: Santali
en ➜ English in locale: Punjabi (Arabic)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Germany)
en ➜ engleză in locale: Romanian (Moldova)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Bosnian
en ➜ English in locale: English (Finland)
en ➜ Ingelsk in locale: Western Frisian
en ➜ อังกฤษ in locale: Thai
en ➜ inglizcha in locale: Uzbek (Uzbekistan)
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Taita (Kenya)
en ➜ anglese in locale: Interlingua (Latin, world)
en ➜ Ааҥыллыы in locale: Sakha (Cyrillic, Russia)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Seychelles)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Uganda)
en ➜ English in locale: English (New Zealand)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Zarma
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Uruguay)
en ➜ nkʉtʉ́k ɔ́ɔ̄ nkɨ́resa in locale: Masai (Kenya)
en ➜ ইংলিস in locale: Manipuri (India)
en ➜ английский in locale: Russian (Ukraine)
en ➜ Anglëe in locale: Sango (Central African Republic)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Fiji)
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German (Liechtenstein)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Barbados)
en ➜ eŋgâlâskielâ in locale: Inari Sami (Finland)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Croatian (Bosnia & Herzegovina)
en ➜ Èdè Gẹ̀ẹ́sì in locale: Yoruba (Latin, Nigeria)
en ➜ Englisch in locale: German (Austria)
en ➜ Lingelesa in locale: Luba-Katanga (Congo - Kinshasa)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (world)
en ➜ Ingiriisi in locale: Somali (Somalia)
en ➜ angļu in locale: Latvian (Latvia)
en ➜ ئینگلیزی in locale: Central Kurdish
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Kuwait)
en ➜ енглески in locale: Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)
en ➜ Ichi Sungu in locale: Bemba
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Danish
en ➜ Engliš in locale: Walser
en ➜ English in locale: English (Lesotho)
en ➜ Bekee in locale: Igbo
en ➜ English in locale: English (Hong Kong SAR China)
en ➜ अंग्रेज़ी in locale: Bodo (Devanagari, India)
en ➜ Kĩngeretha in locale: Meru (Latin, Kenya)
en ➜ ингалсан in locale: Chechen (Russia)
en ➜ ინგლისური in locale: Georgian (Georgia)
en ➜ Kiingereza in locale: Swahili (Tanzania)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Rwanda)
en ➜ Anglisy in locale: Malagasy (Madagascar)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Latin, United States)
en ➜ англисаг in locale: Ossetic (Russia)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Serbian (Latin, Serbia)
en ➜ англисче in locale: Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan)
en ➜ Tanglizt in locale: Central Atlas Tamazight (Latin, Morocco)
en ➜ Engels in locale: Dutch (Latin, Netherlands)
en ➜ îngilîzî in locale: Kurdish (Latin, Turkey)
en ➜ Gĩthungũ in locale: Kikuyu
en ➜ angle in locale: Morisyen (Latin, Mauritius)
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian Bokmål
en ➜ इंग्लीश in locale: Konkani
en ➜ Ǹkɔ́bɔ éngəlís in locale: Ewondo
en ➜ engelsk in locale: Norwegian Nynorsk
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Jordan)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Galician (Latin, Spain)
en ➜ английски in locale: Bulgarian
en ➜ ingles in locale: Kabuverdianu
en ➜ i-English in locale: Zulu
en ➜ англисче in locale: Kyrgyz (Cyrillic, Kyrgyzstan)
en ➜ እንግሊዝኛ in locale: Amharic (Ethiopia)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Algeria)
en ➜ དབྱིན་ཇིའི་སྐད། in locale: Tibetan (China)
en ➜ jendźelšćina in locale: Upper Sorbian
en ➜ Ingles Simi in locale: Quechua (Ecuador)
en ➜ ინგლისური in locale: Georgian (Georgian, Georgia)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Montserrat)
en ➜ इंग्लीश in locale: Konkani (Devanagari, India)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Guernsey)
en ➜ Chiingeleza in locale: Makonde (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ ᱟᱝᱜᱽᱨᱮᱡᱤ in locale: Santali (India)
en ➜ енглески in locale: Serbian (Montenegro)
en ➜ engelska in locale: Swedish (Sweden)
en ➜ Ínglish in locale: Nigerian Pidgin
en ➜ Ааҥыллыы in locale: Sakha
en ➜ Kĩngeretha in locale: Meru
en ➜ English in locale: English (Zambia)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Mali)
en ➜ Turanci in locale: Hausa (Nigeria)
en ➜ saozneg in locale: Breton
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
en ➜ انگلیسی in locale: Persian (Afghanistan)
en ➜ Ingles in locale: Filipino (Latin, Philippines)
en ➜ angličtina in locale: Slovak
en ➜ Ingliffa in locale: Oromo (Latin, Ethiopia)
en ➜ англисаг in locale: Ossetic (Georgia)
en ➜ ئینگلیزی in locale: Central Kurdish (Arabic, Iraq)
en ➜ ענגליש in locale: Yiddish (world)
en ➜ ഇംഗ്ലീഷ് in locale: Malayalam
en ➜ English in locale: English (Malta)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Ghana)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Israel)
en ➜ engelska in locale: Swedish
en ➜ ಇಂಗ್ಲಿಷ್ in locale: Kannada (Kannada, India)
en ➜ Tanglizt in locale: Central Atlas Tamazight (Morocco)
en ➜ Αγγλικά in locale: Greek (Greek, Greece)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Koyraboro Senni (Mali)
en ➜ Kyingereza in locale: Rwa (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ Wašíčuiyapi in locale: Lakota (United States)
en ➜ अंगरेज़ी in locale: Sindhi (Devanagari)
en ➜ Poo in locale: Vai (Latin, Liberia)
en ➜ îngilîzî in locale: Kurdish
en ➜ Kiingereza in locale: Swahili (Congo - Kinshasa)
en ➜  in locale: Fulah (Adlam, Mauritania)
en ➜ Ingles in locale: Filipino (Philippines)
en ➜ inglese in locale: Italian (Vatican City)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Philippines)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Spain)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Colombia)
en ➜ английски in locale: Bulgarian (Bulgaria)
en ➜ English in locale: English (St. Vincent & Grenadines)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Koyraboro Senni (Latin, Mali)
en ➜ Kɨŋgele in locale: Aghem
en ➜ jendźelšćina in locale: Upper Sorbian (Germany)
en ➜ ingeles in locale: Basque (Latin, Spain)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Europe)
en ➜ engelska in locale: Swedish (Latin, Sweden)
en ➜ الإنجليزية in locale: Arabic (Sudan)
en ➜ Turanci in locale: Hausa (Niger)
en ➜ English in locale: English (St. Kitts & Nevis)
en ➜ Kĩthungu in locale: Embu
en ➜ engleză in locale: Romanian (Romania)
en ➜ engleski in locale: Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Guatemala)
en ➜ Engeleere in locale: Fulah (Latin, Liberia)
en ➜ Hɔp u ŋgisì in locale: Basaa (Cameroon)
en ➜ isi-Ngisi in locale: North Ndebele (Latin, Zimbabwe)
en ➜ anglais in locale: French (Madagascar)
en ➜ inglés in locale: Spanish (Chile)
en ➜ англи in locale: Mongolian
en ➜ Kingereza in locale: Kamba (Kenya)
en ➜ انگلیسی in locale: Persian (Iran)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Macao SAR China)
en ➜ 英語 in locale: Japanese (Japanese, Japan)
en ➜ Àngale in locale: Wolof
en ➜ ⵜⴰⵏⴳⵍⵉⵣⵜ in locale: Tachelhit (Tifinagh)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Belize)
en ➜ Wašíčuiyapi in locale: Lakota (Latin, United States)
en ➜ anglisht in locale: Albanian (Albania)
en ➜ engleză in locale: Romanian (Latin, Romania)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Tasawaq (Niger)
en ➜ Ngɛ̄lɛ̄n in locale: Kwasio (Cameroon)
en ➜ ஆங்கிலம் in locale: Tamil (Tamil, India)
en ➜ Taglizit in locale: Kabyle (Latin, Algeria)
en ➜ инҝилис in locale: Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Northern Mariana Islands)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Grenada)
en ➜ iňlis dili in locale: Turkmen
en ➜ Ishingelesa in locale: Sangu (Latin, Tanzania)
en ➜ Tanglizt in locale: Tachelhit (Latin)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Botswana)
en ➜ Taglizit in locale: Kabyle (Algeria)
en ➜ אנגלית in locale: Hebrew (Israel)
en ➜ Chiingeleza in locale: Makonde (Tanzania)
en ➜ ஆங்கிலம் in locale: Tamil (Malaysia)
en ➜ engelska in locale: Swedish (Finland)
en ➜ isi-Ngisi in locale: North Ndebele (Zimbabwe)
en ➜ Lusungu in locale: Luyia (Latin, Kenya)
en ➜ ইংলিস in locale: Manipuri (Bangla)
en ➜ अङ्ग्रेजी in locale: Nepali
en ➜ English in locale: English (Ireland)
en ➜ 英语 in locale: Chinese (Singapore)
en ➜ ඉංග්‍රීසි in locale: Sinhala (Sinhala, Sri Lanka)
en ➜ English in locale: English (Kiribati)
en ➜ Inglisi senni in locale: Tasawaq (Latin, Niger)
en ➜ Ingliffa in locale: Oromo (Ethiopia)
en ➜ ອັງກິດ in locale: Lao (Lao, Laos)
…
```

Answer (score 1):

The method [Locale.getLanguage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage--) gives it

```
Locale l = Locale.ENGLISH;
System.out.println(l.getLanguage()); // en
```

Comment: Locale.ENGLISH it is already tag. I have only a string with displayed language.